# Display Alpha character for each item in each_with_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a list of users that I iterate through in my erb. The intent is for them to be anonymized so what I'm doing is:

```
  <%  @event.users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
       Person <%= index %>
  <% end %>
```

and what I get is:

> Person 1
>
> Person 2
>
> Person 3

However, what I actually want is to display an alpha character for each index like:

> Person A
>
> Person B
>
> Person C

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: What should happen if there are, say, 32 people in the list?

Comment: it will by default `"Z".next  => "AA"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do something like this.

```
  <% alp = "A" %>
  <%  @event.users.each do |user| %>
       Person <%= alp %>
       <% alp = alp.next %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, that works. I was stuck on trying to manipulate the index.